# Can malware infect a router and spread to other devices connected to it?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, virus, malware

Suppose my computer gets malware. I can deal with it by reinstalling the OS with an installation usb from a different pc but is it possible for the malware to infect the wifi router and then spread to other devices connected to it? Or even reinstall the malware via the router?

Should I worry about this and take steps to clean the router even if I have no signs of such a router malware or should I wait and see if the malware spreads via the router?

Threat model: Regular computer user.

Comment: I know I made a similar post here but it's worded like I manage a network or something. I marked it for deletion.

Comment: Note that in order for a router to "infect" client devices, those devices would need to expose a vulnerability in the OS network stack or a network service that the router is capable of exploiting. An infected router can do lots of bad things to your clients, but most of them involve tricking the user into going to the wrong place (phishing), degrading connection security (HTTPS, VPN, etc) or manipulating data as it passes through the system. compromised routers are often used in botnets for DDOS attacks against a third party.

Comment: Yes; It’s **absolutely** possible for malware to be targeted to network devices that can be exploited, and the malware can be designed, to spread additional malicious payloads. Instead of submitting what virtually is the same question you should have edited your question so it could have been reopened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routers have been infected and are vulnerable to exploits,
especially routers with older versions of Linux that contain known
vulnerabilities.

The router contains an operating system (OS), so is vulnerable to
malware, such as
[VPNFilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPNFilter)
and Switcher Trojan. It's also vulnerable when weak passwords are
used, or when protected by a PIN which is far easier to crack
than a password.

While many routers use a Linux-based OS,
some manufacturers create their own.
The
[2018 cryptomining attack targeting MikroTik routers](https://blog.avast.com/mikrotik-routers-targeted-by-cryptomining-campaign-avast)
is a notorious example of malicious scripts targeting
specific router operating systems.

> should I wait and see if the malware spreads via the router?

When you suspect an infection, you should never wait.
The more you wait, the more the infection will spread,
until it becomes impossible to eradicate.

A router is easily cleaned out, by simply doing a factory reset.
The factory firmware is digitally signed, so is almost impossible
to corrupt. The factory reset will return it to a pristine condition.

Even a simple reset of the router can eradicate most known viruses,
as they mostly infect the memory-resident and post-reset firmware.
Resetting the router from time to time is good practice.

As precaution,
you should always update your router with the latest firmware,
and also regard old routers with no updates coming for several years
with great mistrust.

Comment: Got an infection 2 months ago and alredy dealt with it (on the infected computer). I see no evidence of such a router malware. Is it worth doing the format anyway?

Comment: Your decision, but there is no formatting involved. Factory reset is problematic since it will lose you all your router settings, but simple reset by turning it off and on will do no harm.

Comment: I've alredy done a simple reset and will do a factory reset if I see signs of router malware. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Routers (the ones I use) have firmware. Firmware is updated by the router vendor with specific signatures in the update tool. This assuming the firmware is the vendor firmware and not altered (which changes things)

Most unlikely (98% or more) that a standard and good router will not / cannot be infected.

Nothing to clean out.